# Problem regarding Investments and selling the right.

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

I have trouble solving the following problem algebraically.

> Smith lends $\$1000$ to Jones at time $t=0$. Jones is supposed to repay Smith by paying $\$100$ at time $t=1$ and $2$, and $\$1000$ at time $t=3$.  However, Simth sells the right for the money being paid back to Brown at time $t=1.5$ for $\$1000$.  Let $j$ be the interest rate rate earned per unit time for Smith and $k$ be that of Brown.  Which is larger, $j$ or $k$?

Intuitively, clearly $j>k$ because Smith gets back his $\$1000$ earlier than Brown, and they both receive an extra $\$100$.

However, I cannot prove this inequality for some reason.

The following is what I tried.

The total amount Smith is going to have at $t=4$ , $S$, can be calculated as

$$S=-1000(1+j)^4+100(1+j)^3 +1000(1+j)^{2.5}$$

Likewise, the total amount Brown is going to have at $t=4$ , $B$, can be calculated as

$$B=-1000(1+k)^{2.5}+100(1+k)^2+1000$$

I don't know the relationship between $S$ and $B$ besides the fact that $S>B$.  Can someone help me out?

I have a feeling that I am not doing this problem correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For me the best way of thinking about problems of this kind is to notice that the unknown interest rate $j$ represents the interest rate for the account with the same cash flow, i.e. to imagine Smith pays into his account (with interest rate $j$ per annum) 1000$\$$, then after one year withdraws 100$\$$, and after 1.5 year he has in the account $1000\$$. We get:

$(1000(1+j) - 100)*(1+j)^{0.5}=1000$ 
and this an be easily solved for $j$.